# Where the fxc.exe is located in Windows SDK?

Tags: directx

I'm using Windows SDK under Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2013. Where I can find fxc? I do not use old Directx SDK.

Comment: For the future generations in this and all similar cases: Run search on your system disc.

Answer (score 2):

For the future generations: the path to fxc.exe is desribed here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk/

On my Windows 7 the path looks like this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86

Comment: Search for 'Visual Studio Tools' and then start "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013".

Comment: the link in this post no longer works